# TortoiseSVN on windows to commit a linux directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My desktop is windows (7) machine and I use putty to work / code on remote linux machine.  I created an svn repository for a project I'm working on, on the local harddisk of my linux machine, and then checked out the project into linux homedir (which is nfs).

I really like the features of TortoiseSVN and want to use it manage this project from my windows machine via a samba mount of my homedir. 
Currently, I've set up my TortoiseSVN to point to the repo via
`svn+ssh://me@mylinuxbox/local/svn-repo/myproject/`

Updating the project is fine, but  whenever I try to commit changes via TortoiseSVN, I get the following error:

`Commit failed (details follow):
Can't move 'F:\myproject\.svn\tmp\svn-D7BC2F42' to
 'F:\myproject\.svn\pristine\0d\0dd5fb7735036827c776e6ebadda82250ad497d9.svn-base':
 Access is denied.`

Here, F: is the samba mount of my homedir.

Any suggestions / pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to modify files on your f: drive using other Windows tools? - e.g. move a file using Windows Explorer or edit a text file using Notepad.

Comment: Yes. I can edit / access my F: from windows without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Don't place repositories|Working Copies on shares - it's more headache, than fun

Checkout your repo into local WC on local drive in your Winbox

Comment: The problem is that I need to run the code on my linux machine. I just want to use TortoiseSVN on my windows machine to do version control. So creating a WC on my windows machine won't really help me.

Comment: Then use an svn client on your linux machine. Crossing OSes w/ SVN clients via shares is just going to give you headaches.

Comment: @firdaus - **don't reinvent the wheel!!!**. The are a lot of different deploy tools... "Deploy for beggars": svn export in post-commit hook

Comment: @LazyBadger could you elaborate ? what is deploy for beggars ?

Comment: @firdaus - I **wrote** it. *`svn export` in post-commit hook*... or svn up in LinuxWC